# How can i trigger basic http auth and send user info in realtime?

Tags: authentication, python-requests

I have just tried

```
=============================== 
        # Give user the file requested 
        url = "http://superhost.gr/data/files/%s" % realfile 

        username = getpass.getuser() 
        password = getpass.getpass() 

        r = requests.get( url, auth = (username, password) )        # ask user for authentication data 
        r.raise_for_status() 
===============================
```

as well as input() for both user & pass combo but iam not getting in chrome the basic pop-up HTTP auth window.

Any idea why?

How can i ASK the user for http auth data and store them isntead of giving them to the script?

Comment: I used to have this workaround solution for triggering the web server to pop-up the HTTP Auth window 

print '''<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://superhost.gr/data/files/%s">''' % file_requested 

and i have tried to read the the login auth name that user entered by using 

authuser = os.environ.get( 'REMOTE_USER', 'Άγνωστος' ) 

unfortunately it always failes to receive it that's why i'm trying to do the trick with the requests module.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use below code to ask user for credentials and send them via `HTTP` request

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests
import sys

username = sys.argv[1]
password = sys.argv[2]
realfile = sys.argv[3]

url = "http://superhost.gr/data/files/%s" % realfile 
r = requests.get( url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
print(r.status_code)
```

This script user can run as `python script.py username password filename`

Comment: Thank you but unofrtuntely it wont do because this script requires parameters to be given via console. My script is a python cgi-script and the parameters username and password must be inserted on Apache's basic http auth popup windows.

Comment: You mean those values should be default credentials or what? When you use `HTTP` requests actually there are no pop-ups :) This should be done on a server side. Can you tell me who are your users and how they will use your script?

Comment: When basic HTTP auth windows pop-up(and it must :-) then the user will be authenticated becuse only at the time he will provide the auth info which then will be in the hands of .htaccess and .htpasswd if it authenticates successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Give user the file requested 

print('''<meta http-equiv="refresh" 
content="5;url=http://superhost.gr/data/files/%s">''' % realfile) 

authuser = os.environ.get( 'REMOTE_USER', 'Άγνωστος' ) 
print( authuser ) 
================================
```

Trying this, feels liek i'm almost there except that when printing the value of authuser variable it default to "Άγνωστος" meaning not there.

is there any other way i can grab what the user gave a auth login info?